# disable people picker 2010

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-form

I am using following "code" to disable people picker in custom edit form:

```
$("div[id$='_UserField_upLevelDiv']").attr("contentEditable",false);//Disabling People picker
$("span[id$='_UserField']").find("img").hide(); //hiding search field and check which are adjacent to people picker
```

Control is disabled but when there is something (or rather someone) in the field already, I can select that person and delete it by pressing delete on the keyboard. 
Is there a way of restricting that behavior?

Just found out that it is working fine in IE10 but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a half answer, because I am not sure why this works.  If you only set disabled or if you only set contenteditable, the field can still be edited.  However, if you set both, it works as desired.

```
 $("div[id$='_UserField_upLevelDiv']").attr({
    "contenteditable": false, 
    "disabled": "disabled"
});
```

Also, if you are using `jQuery 1.6+`, you want [to use prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).  I tested with an old `jQuery` version, so I left my answer using `attr`.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. the same behavior. When checked in IE, both are working fine.In Chrome I can delete people picker value.

Comment: I was able to reproduce in chrome.  This amended answer worked for me.